# For which type of table attributes does the database system automatically create indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For which type of table attributes does the database system automatically create indexes ?

Comment: None TABLE option performs automatic index creation.

Comment: Indexes are not created based on the type of columns.  They are created explicitly, based on `unique`/`primary key` conditions, or in MySQL for foreign key constraints.